# Efficiently collating the number of method calls per thread via Byte Buddy?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I am currently using byte buddy to add some simple logic that counts the number of total method invocations on a per thread basis.

For advice instrumentation, I have something along the lines of:

```
 @Advice.OnMethodEnter
 static void handle() {
   MethodCounter.increment();
 }
```

In `MethodCounter#increment`, I have a very simple `ThreadLocal` counter, and the counter itself just increments an integer:

```
public class MethodCounter {
    final ThreadLocal<Counter> threadCounter = new ThreadLocal<Counter>();
    public static void increment() {
        threadCounter.get().increment();
    }

    ... and some other logic that ensures that the Counter is initialized for the current thread ...
}
```

When using JMH to benchmark this new logic, I am noticing about a 30% degradation in performance in a sample workflow (containing tight loops).  Most of this seems to be due to the `ThreadLocal` -- if I instead get rid of the `ThreadLocal.get()` and hardcoding `increment()` to increment a static `Counter`, there is minimal performance impact.

Is there a more performant way to accomplish this with byte buddy while maintaining per-thread isolation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a class is instrumented, Byte Buddy really is out of the picture.

To avoid the expensive thread local, you can try using [weak lock free](https://github.com/raphw/weak-lock-free) which uses a concurrent map on a thread basis and can perform better. In general, thread-locals are however somewhat expensive, especially if you look them up a lot and there is no good way around it.